# Why can I not use a return value from a function that is outside the render method, inside the render method in ReactNative?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a function defined inside a component, but outside the render method. It is a query connecting to a server and checking login credentials. The function does work properly, the query does as well, the only issue is that when I try to use the return value of the function `this._onPressed` in an if statement inside the render method of the component, it does not seem to properly return a boolean value which I can use in my if/else statement.

Below is the entire code of my frontend:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { username:'', password:''}
    }


    _onPress = () => {
        axios.post('http://192.168.137.1:3000/login', {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput style= {styles.input}
                            autoCapitalize="none"
                            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username: text})}
                            onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            keyboardType={'email-address'}
                            returnKeyType="next"
                            placeholder="Enter Email or Mobile Number"
                            placeholderTextColor='rgba(115,115,115,0.8)'/>

                <TextInput style={styles.input}
                            returnKeyType="go"
                            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
                            ref={(input)=> this.passwordInput = input} //What does this do???
                            placeholder="Password"
                            placeholderTextColor='rgba(115,115,115,0.8)'
                            secureTextEntry/>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}
                                    onPress={() => this._onPress() == true ? this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') : alert('Login failed')} >
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonSignupContainer}
                                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Signup')}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonSignupText}>Sign Up</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 20,
        marginBottom: 50,
    },
    input: {
        height: 40,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(225,225,225,0.8)',
        marginBottom: 10,
        padding: 10,
        color: '#737373'
    },
    buttonContainer:{
        backgroundColor: '#38B74C',
        paddingVertical: 15
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: '#fff',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontWeight: '700',
    },
    buttonSignupContainer: {
        paddingTop:15,
    },
    buttonSignupText: {
        opacity: 0.5,
        textAlign: 'center',
    }
})

export default withNavigation(LoginForm);
```

Here is the query request to my server:

```
    _onPress = () => {
    axios.post('http://192.168.137.1:3000/login', {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

And here is the onPress function of my button that is of concern:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}
                                onPress={() => this._onPress() == true ? this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') : alert('Login failed')} >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

It just always returns the else value, even when I am 100% sure that it should return the first value. I also tested it with log statements inside the query response, that definitely indicated me that true is being returned by the function, but once it gets to the if statement in the onPress prop it does not behave correctly anymore.

Answer (score 0):

it does not work because _onPress is not returning a Boolean it is returning a [Promise](https://www.newline.co/fullstack-react/30-days-of-react/day-15/). you can achieve your goal with something like this:

```
onPress={() => this._onPress() == true ? this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') : alert('Login failed')}
```

to

```
onPress={async () => await this._onPress() == true ? this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') : alert('Login failed')}
```

howevener even this is not a clean code. I suggest you move the whole alert section to _onPress

```
_onPress = () => {
axios.post('http://192.168.137.1:3000/login', {
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password
})
.then(function (response) {
    if(response.data)
           this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') 
    else 
           alert('Login failed')
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

}

in general it is a best practice to keep any semantic OUTSIDE the render function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the first option with the not so clean approach does not change anything for me. The second option works semantic wise, like before, but it won't let me navigate to a different screen from outside the render function. (I have no idea why, though)